# C# Create a Timer that counts up in mm:ss and can preform actions at 'x' minute

Tags: c#, timer

Hey I am creating a program that interacts with another and I am trying to set up a timer!

I want a timer that counts up in mm:ss format

```
    int seconds = 0;
    int minutes = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        seconds++;
        lblView.Text = seconds.ToString();

    }
```

Right now I am at the stage where I have a label going up in seconds but, I want it to show both minutes and seconds. I looked it up and I read a bit about TimeSpan https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287(v=vs.110).aspx

I have come across this method:

```
public static double ConvertSecondsToMinutes(double seconds)
    {
        return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).TotalMinutes;
    }
```

But not sure how to implement it into my code. I am looking for the right way to do this. Thank you

Comment: What are you not sure of? What have you tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

.ToString on a TimeSpan object takes a formatter.

```
int seconds = 0;
int minutes = 0;
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seconds++;
    lblView.Text = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds).ToString("mm\\:ss");

}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
int seconds = 0;
int minutes = 0;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    seconds++;
    minutes = (int)Math.Floor(seconds / 60);
    lblView.Text =  minutes.ToString() + ":" + (seconds % 60).ToString();
}
```

Comment: You need to cast `(seconds / 60)` to decimal or double: `minutes = (int)Math.Floor((decimal)(seconds / 60));` else you'll encounter an error saying: `The call is ambiguous`.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime.Now;

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblView.Text = string.Format("{0:mm\\:ss}", DateTime.Now - dt);
}
```

Then you don't even have to increment, and you can be sure it's the exact amount of seconds and minutes between each time.